# Global variables in onEdit / onOpen

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a question for you - how to declare global/public variable that will work in onEdit(evt)?

I want to set variables when document will be opened (not every time when something will be edited via onEdit function)

```
var cbx_kod = "some initial val";
var cbx_Nazwa = "some initial val";
var cbx_Ilosc = "some initial val";

function onOpen(evt) {

     //lets set them
     cbx_kod = something.getValue(); 
     cbx_Nazwa = something.getValue();
     cbx_Ilosc = something.getValue();

}

function onEdit(evt) {

//code

   if(col == cbx_kod ){
   //something
   }
}
```

The problem is - it doesn't work. When I open workbook - it works until I edit something. Opening set proper values, then when I edit it - values goes to initial value.

Answer (score 1):

- The variables set in the scope of function `onOpen` wil retain the assigned values only within this function
- `onEdit` is a separate function that does not interact with `onOpen`.
- It will  use the variables as defined globally (at the beginning of your script, independent of `onOpen`), unless you give them a new definition inside `onEdit`

### What you can do to communicate between `onOpen` and `onEdit`

- Use [propertiesService](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/properties/properties-service)
- It allows you to set variable values into a cache that can be retrieved when you need it

Sample

```
var scriptProperties = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties();

//to be run once
function myStartFunction(){
    scriptProperties.setProperty('cbx_kod', '"some initial val"');
}

function onOpen(evt) {
     //lets set them
     cbx_kod = something.getValue(); 
     scriptProperties.setProperty('cbx_kod', cbx_kod);
}

function onEdit(evt) {
  var cbx_kod = scriptProperties.getProperty('cbx_kod');
   if(col == cbx_kod ){
   //something
   }
}
```